# How to predict a value from a dataset in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, predict

## The point

My question is "How to predict a value from a dataset in JavaScript?". To explain my problem, I'm going to take an example of the result I want.

If you're using Mathematica, you probably know that there is a `Predict[]` function. And I thought that it could be awesome if I could do a similar function in JavaScript. I know that the Mathematica function is using Machine Learning and other cool and technical stuff that I don't really know more about, so, to keep it simple, I tried to implement this `Predict[]` function through what I call "Affine transformation prediction".

If you remember from school, affine functions are written like `f(x)=ax+b`.

and I know that from 2 values, you can easily know what is `a` and `b`.

## My implementation

Here is my code for the moment:

```
function predict(array1, array2, val) {
    var first = array1[0]
    var second = array2[0]
    var firstVal = array1[1]
    var secondVal = array2[1]
    var a = (firstVal - secondVal) / (first - second)
    var b = secondVal - (second * a)
    return val * b;
}
```

So, the `array1` one will be the "start" value (I don't know the word in English, but in French it's "antecedent"), and the image of the function.

The `array2` will be the same, but for a different "start" value and image.

The `val` will be where does the function have to predict the value.

### Example of how it works:

Let's say we have the function `f(x)=2x+1`, we know that `1->3` and `2->5` works. So, we want to know (without knowing the function of course ) what `f(3)` will give us, so we write:

```
predict([1,3],[2,5],3)
```

And, normally, it will return 7.

## My problem

The main problem of this function is the way it works. I would like to simplify it. Let me explain, I would a function that looks like that:

```
function predict(object, val) {
    ...
}
```

Where `object` is something like: `{ 1: 3, 2: 5, 4: 9}`. Something like a JSON object with 2 or more values in it, to be I guess more precise, but also to have the word "dataset" in it. Because, the problem is that currently, the function can't be called a `predict` function because it's more an `affineTransformationFinder` function.

Manipulating object in JavaScript is way simpler than an array for many many reasons that you'll understand.

I tried to explain my point and I hope  you'll agree with me. If you have any question, don't hesitate to add a comment, I'll be happy  to answer it.

Comment: What's stopping you doing it the second way? Can't you just iterate through the object's keys?

Comment: Well, 2 things: how to get the « start » value, because you can’t do obj[0] and how to do it for multiple values @Jonah

Comment: Have a look at the Object.keys() method, which returns an array of all the object's keys https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: Thank you , but how do I manage multiple values?

Comment: @ArthurGuiot Have you considered some sort of regression? Least squares would do just fine.

Comment: @ArthurGuiot Object.keys() returns all keys of the object, so `Object.keys({1:3,2:5,4:9})` returns `[1,2,4]`, if that's what you mean by managing "multiple values"

Comment: @Jonah Thank you very much . If you want, you can right down the answer, so I can up vote and mark your answer as right ✅

Comment: @ArthurGuiot I totally forgot about this! Just got around to posting it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys()` is what you're looking for - when passed an object, it returns an array of its keys, which you can iterate through and pass back into the object to retrieve the property values.